# Compiling a trusted resource url in angular through a filter and directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular with the angular-dashboard library 
https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard.

I am strugling to insert an iframe widget where the src url is not blocked by $sce.

I create the widgetDefinitions as follows:

```
.factory('widgetDefinitions', function($sce) {
return [
  {
    name: 'iframe',
    directive: 'iframe',
    attrs: {
        url: 'http://www.google.nl',
    }
  }
 ];
})
```

I pass the dashboardOptions:

```
$scope.dashboardOptions = {
        widgetButtons: true,
        widgetDefinitions: widgetDefinitions,
        defaultWidgets: defaultWidgets,
        storage: window.localStorage,
        storageId: 'explicitSave',
        explicitSave: true
    };
```

I have a directive for the iframe widget:

```
.directive('iframe', [function ($compile, $parse) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: true,
  replace: true,
  template: '<iframe id="iframe" src="url | unsafehtml"></iframe>', 
  link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch(attr.url, function() {
                            element.html($parse(attr.url)(scope));
                            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }, true);
  }
};
```

}]);

And a filter to parse the unsafehtml

```
angular.module('monitors').filter('unsafehtml', ['$sce',
function($sce) {
    return function(input) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    };
}
]);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [http://www.google.nl] starting at [://www.google.nl].
```

I have tried some other options:
- setting the url in widgetDefinitions to $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl and removing the unsafehtml filter
- setting the url without the unsafehtml filter, by using {{url}} in the template and scope.url to set the url.

However, without luck. After reading through most of the stackoverflow questions about this, still not solved. Any tips and suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(input);` instead of `$sce.trustAsHtml(input);`

Search 'iframe' in the angular [$sce docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce).

Comment: Thank you for replying. This might be a necessary change, but the error is still there. My guess is the issue is within the $scope.$watch. Since the attr.url is a value, it cannot parse it. However, I am unsure how to change this into something that will execute the filter on the url and then compile the template to replace the {{url}} with the src value.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it with $sce.RESOURCE_URL ? I'm attempting to implement the Malhar angular dashboard as well, and having a bit of trouble with the 'dataModelType' of 'widgetDefinitions' property.

Answer (score 0):

You might use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://sampleTemplete.html') instead of $sce.trustAsHtml('sampleTemplete.html'). Working simple example to avoid error:

```
//Directive for <sample-templete></sample-templete>
app.directive('sampleTemplete', function($sce) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://sampleTemplete.html')
    };  
});
```